# Python 3 interpreter saying index out of range even though it's not

Tags: python, arrays, list, python-3.x, indexoutofboundsexception

this is a simple code to test whether a list is mirrored or not. i am testing it with list variable 'l', which is a mirrored list. however, the compiler points out an error that the list index is out of range. and i have figuerd out that the problem lies within the initial value of variable 'begin'. but i don't see anything wrong here.

```
l = ['x', 'y', 'z', 'z', 'y', 'x']

mirror = 0
begin = 0
end = 5
while begin != end:
    if l[begin] == l[end]:
        begin += 1
        end -= 1
    else:
        mirror = -1
        begin = end
if mirror == 0:
    print('mirrored')
else:
    print('NO!')
```

Comment: Hint: put `print(begin, end)` just after this line: `while begin != end:`

Comment: hmm, looks like if i change the while condition to that 'begin' cannot be greater than half of the list length (which is 2 here), then it works. i understand that the previous condition was silly, but WHY did it not work? what was the computer actually doing when it was following the [while begin!=end] condition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Reason for problem:**

```
begin end
 0     5
 1     4
 2     3
 3     2
 4     1
 5     0
```

So, `begin` was never equal to `end`. And when `begin` was `5`, after

```
if l[begin] == l[end]:       #if l[5] == l[0]
    begin += 1               #begin is now 6
    end -= 1
```

`begin` beomes `6`, which is out of bound. 
**Now Solution:**

```
l = ['x', 'y', 'z', 'z', 'y', 'x']

mirror = 0
begin = 0
end = 5
while begin != len(l):
    if l[begin] == l[end]:
        begin += 1
        end -= 1
    else:
        mirror = -1
        break            #we don't need to run the loop further
if mirror == 0:
    print('mirrored')
else:
    print('NO!')
```

Comment: And a good one at that, @rakuzi. Keep it up and welcome on Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 2):

You're getting an index out of range error because your "begin" index is increasing without bound. When "begin" gets to 5, it tries to access l[5], which is out of bounds. Adding the additional constraint:

```
while begin != end and begin < len(l):
```

will allow your code to run fine. That said, there are plenty of built-in ways to accomplish what you're trying to do easier, but I'm sure you already know that :)